# NUnit - prevent concurrent testing on same OS (mutex)?

Tags: nunit

Is there something built into NUnit that will prevent concurrent testing happening on the same OS host?

Long story but on CI server, two build agents running concurrently cause problems for tests using local resources (disk, DBs, etc.).

Else, I'll have to add my own mutex in the init and teardown methods.

(v2.6.4)

Comment: I think that's why agents should have their own system :)

Comment: What'd be cool, in future, is if they could use the OS virtualization technologies, like Docker does.

Comment: Which CI system are you using?

Comment: TeamCity. It's mostly fine to run agents on the same OS, though I totally take your point, so if the agents could run virtualized w/o the weight of a whole VM it'd be cool.

Comment: Back to your question, but no - I think there is nothing builtin. But as you probably know it's very simple, have a setupfixture for all of your assemblies, and then take a mutex in the setup method. That should be alright.

Comment: I guess you could add a proper answer saying, "No, there isn't".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't.

I would try to use a SetupFixture that creates a mutex.